# How to build a KStream from SubscriableChannel

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm working with Spring cloud streams and wanted to fiddle with KStreams/KTables a little.

I'm looking for the methodology of going from a standard Kafka topic to turn it into a stream.

I've done this in KSQL but I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to have SpringBoot handle this.  The best I can find is examples where both `@Input` and `@Output` channels are already `KStreams` but I think that is not what I want.

#### Kafka Setup

Inside of SpringBoot I'm doing the following:

- My data comes on: `force-entities-topic`
- I then "clean" the data removing the `[UTC]` tag from the time message and re-publish on:
  `force-entities-topic-clean`

From there I was hoping to take the output of that and build both a `KStream` and `KTable` keyed on the `platformUID` field.

#### Input data

So the data I'm working with is:

```
{
  "platformUID": "UID",
  "type": "TLPS",
  "state": "PLATFORM_INITIALIZED",
  "fuelremaining": 5.9722E+24,
  "latitude": 39,
  "longitude": -115,
  "altitude": 0,
  "time": "2018-07-18T00:00:00Z[UTC]"
}
```

#### KSQL

I can run these KSQL commands to create what I need.  (Here I'm reading time in as a string as opposed to actual time which I'm doing in the java/kotlin implementation)

```sql
CREATE STREAM force_no_key (
    platformUID string, 
    type string, 
    state string, 
    fuelremaining DOUBLE, 
    latitude DOUBLE, 
    longitude DOUBLE, 
    altitude DOUBLE
  ) with (
    kafka_topic='force-entities-topic', 
    value_format='json');
```

From there I make another stream (because I couldn't get it to read the key correctly)

```sql
CREATE STREAM force_with_key 
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='blue_force_with_key') AS
  select PLATFORMUID as UID, LATITUDE as lat, LONGITUDE as LON, ALTITUDE as ALT, state, type 
  FROM force_no_key 
  PARTITION BY UID;
```

And from this point

```sql
CREATE TABLE FORCE_TABLE
( UID VARCHAR, 
    LAT DOUBLE, 
    LON DOUBLE,
    ALT DOUBLE
) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'force_with_key',
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
        KEY = 'UID');
```

#### Java Style!

Where I'm running into trouble I think is here.  I define my binding interface here:

```
    interface ForceStreams {

        companion object {
            // From the settings file we configure it with the value of-force-in
            const val DIRTY_INPUT = "dirty-force-in"
            const val CLEANED_OUTPUT = "clean-force-out"
            const val CLEANED_INPUT = "clean-force-in"
            const val STREAM_OUT = "stream-out"
        }

        @Input(DIRTY_INPUT)
        fun initialInput(): MessageChannel

        @Output(CLEANED_OUTPUT)
        fun cleanOutput(): SubscribableChannel

        @Input(CLEANED_INPUT)
        fun cleanInput(): MessageChannel

        @Output(STREAM_OUT)
        fun cleanedBlueForceMessage(): KStream<String, ForceEntity>

        @Output(TABLE_OUT)
        fun tableOutput(): KTable<String, ForceEntity>
    }
```

And then I do the cleaning with this block:

```
@StreamListener(ForceStreams.DIRTY_INPUT)
@SendTo(ForceStreams.CLEANED_OUTPUT)
fun forceTimeCleaner(@Payload message: String): ForceEntity {

    var inputMap: Map<String, Any> = objectMapper.readValue(message)

    var map = inputMap.toMutableMap()

    map["type"] = map["type"].toString().replace("-", "_")
    map["time"] = map["time"].toString().replace("[UTC]", "")

    val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map)

    val fe : ForceEntity = objectMapper.readValue(json, ForceEntity::class.java)

    return fe
}
```

But I'm going from `MessageChannel` to `SubscribableChannel`

What I'm unsure how to do is go from `SubscribableChannel` to either `KStream<String,ForceEntity>` or `KTable<String,ForceEntity>`

Any help would be appreciated - thanks

### Edit - applicaiton.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: Blue-Force-Table
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: # This seems to be for the KStreams the other config is for normal streams
      - localhost:19092
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kafka
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:19092
      bindings:
        dirty-force-in:
          destination: force-entities-topic
          contentType: application/json
        clean-force-in:
          destination: force-entities-topic-clean
          contentType: application/json
        clean-force-out:
          destination: force-entities-topic-clean
          contentType: application/json
        stream-out:
          destination: force_stream
          contentType: application/json
        table-out:
          destination: force_table
          contentType: application/json
```

I guess the follow on question is - is this even possible?  Can you mix and match binders within a single function?

Answer (score 0):

In the first `StreamListener`, you are receiving data through `DIRTY_INPUT` binding and writing through the binding `CLEANED_OUTPUT`. Then you need to have another `StreamListener`, where you receive that data as `KStream` and do the processing and write the output.

First processor:

```
@StreamListener(ForceStreams.DIRTY_INPUT)
@SendTo(ForceStreams.CLEANED_OUTPUT)
fun forceTimeCleaner(@Payload message: String): ForceEntity {
....
```

Change the following to a `KStream` binding.

```
@Input(CLEANED_INPUT)
        fun cleanInput(): MessageChannel
```

to

```
@Input(CLEANED_INPUT)
        fun cleanInput(): KStream<String, ForceEntity>
```

Second processor:

```
        @StreamListener(CLEANED_INPUT)
        @SendTo(STREAM_OUT)
        public KStream<String, ForceEntity> process(
                KStream<String, ForceEntity> forceEntityStream) {

            return forceEntityStream
                    ........
                    .toStream();
        }
```

Currently, the Kafka Streams binder in Spring Cloud Stream does not support writing the data out as a `KTable`. Only `KStream` objects are allowed on the output (`KTable` binding is allowed on the input). If that is a hard requirement, you need to look into Spring Kafka where you can go lower level and do that kind of outbound operations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I'm getting an `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The binder 'kafka' cannot bind a com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95` error - I'm assuming its because it never actually created a Stream ... I shall investigate further

Comment: if you can share a minimal reproducible sample, I can take a look further.